# During Hangouts call, HDMI signal dies, does not respond to keystrokes

Tags: hdmi, pi-4

A few minutes after I start a Hangouts video call, the HDMI signal dies. I have disabled the screensaver with `xset s off` and `xset -dpms`. Touching the keyboard or the mouse doesn't help. I can still SSH in. Rebooting the Pi fixes it, as does restarting lightdm.

Device: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B - 4G RAM
Monitor: LG 60UH6150

(Edited with more diagnostics)

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/screensaver.md which has settings to disable. I normally find pressing Shift key wakes up display.

Comment: If it were the screensaver, wouldn't pressing keys help?

Comment: Might be a powering problem. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13872#p144577

Comment: I'm using the official Adafruit power supply. What should I look for in the logs that would indicate a powering problem?